# Expo Router slug folder for parent/{parentId}/child/{childId}

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I would like to ask some idea using Expo Router.

I have decks with a simple routing:

```
 /deck/detail/[id].tsx 
 /deck/form/add/index.ts
 /deck/form/edit/[id].tsx
```

Also I have cards. Cards has relations with decks.

In laravel there is Nested resources for this. It means when you want to edit a child then you should use the next route:

```
parent/{parentId}/child/{childId}
```

I like this idea so if it's possible I want to use something similar in Expo Route for my child.

I would like to create the next routing for cards:

```
/deck/{deckId}/card/edit/[id].tsx
/deck/{deckId}/card/add/index.tsx
```

But I don't know how to implement it in expo router. Is it possible to make "slug" folder?

Actually I can just implement the next solution:

```
/card/edit/[id].tsx  (also passed deckId as router param)
/card/add/[deckId].tsx
```

But I don't feel it enough clean.

What is the best practice to do that?